# margin-top blocked at some value

Tags: css

I have this code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9t9U/) :

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: beige;
}

#menu {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: green;
}

#menu:hover {
    border-top: 15px #f39539 solid !important;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

It works very good but when i was playing with CSS values i found something that i didn't understand.

My question is why when i put value lower than `-15px` in `margin-top`, my menu div  don't go up when i hover over it ?

why `margin-top: -30px;` is the same that `margin-top: -15px;` ?

P.S : `15px` is also the value of my `border-top-width`.

**UPDATE**

and what is weird is when i drop `border-top: 15px #f39539 solid !important;` when i hover, My DIV go up without problem even when i put `margin-top: -50px;` ! [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9t9U/2/)

```
#menu:hover {
    /* border-top: 15px #f39539 solid !important; */
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you unsure about? Your minus margin makes up the width that the border takes. So whenever you change your border, you need to change your margin accordingly.

Comment: why I need to change your margin accordingly ? why when i put lower with in margin it doesn't go up ?

Comment: It works fine for me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: read again my question, for me also everything is okey

Comment: What **exactly** do you need? That margin is there specifically to counter the height that the border brings. A lower margin *does* take it up. http://jsfiddle.net/k9t9U/1/

Comment: `A lower margin does take it up` can you explain me that, this is what i need to understand.

Comment: So you need to understand how margin works? There's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) for that.

Comment: No i understand, take a look at my update and you will understand. when i drop `border-top: 15px #f39539 solid !important;` when i hover, My DIV go up without problem ! [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9t9U/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think if I understand what you are asking is....

What you are seeing is **margin collapse**.

It's when you have two adjoining margins, the largest wins - the smallest is lost.

More details here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins